# AWS Lambda XML to JSON using Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am unable to get callback in JSON format when trying to convert XML to JSON in AWS Lambda and API gateway integration.

Code :

```
enter code here

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<Name>Sayyed Abbas</Name>";
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
var r = JSON.stringify(result)
console.dir(r);
callback(null,event.r);
});
};
```

The Output, I see in AWS is below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K78iK.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use toJson method in xml2json module. It works perfectly for me.

```
let xmlParser = require('xml2json');
let xml = "<Name>Sayyed Abbas</Name>";
console.log('JSON output', xmlParser.toJson(xml));
```

Comment: Anytime. Incase if my answer helped you to solve the problem accept it as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Where did you define xml2json?

Comment: It is a npm module(https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json). Sorry that I didn't mention it before since it has already been used in the question. I updated my answer.